# Get current/ oldest values from a table for each customer based on dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table which tracks customer names, what US State they live in, and when they moved there. Here is sample code to create this:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (Customer_Name VARCHAR(20), Residence_State VARCHAR(20), Move_In_Date DATE)

INSERT INTO @Customers VALUES
('Rachel', 'Wisconsin', '2010-01-01'),
('Rachel', 'Nevada', '2012-06-03'),
('Rachel', 'Arizona', '2018-02-01'),
('Chad', 'Texas', '2010-01-01'),
('Chad', 'Idaho', '2012-04-15'),
('Chad', 'Texas', '2019-11-17'),
('Jake', 'Illinois', '2010-01-01'),
('Jake', 'Florida', '2011-02-04'),
('Jake', 'Wisconsin', '2013-08-13'),
('Jake', 'California', '2016-01-15')
```

Given this table, I would like to get a row for each customer that showed their name, their oldest known State of residence, and their current State of residence. So for the data above, that would be:

```
Rachel - Wisconsin - Arizona
Chad - Texas - Texas
Jake - Illinois - California
```

What is the most efficient way to write this query?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like SQL Server.  Unfortunately, there is not a `first()` aggregation function.  But you can use `first_value()`:

```
select distinct customer_name,
       first_value(residence_state) over (partition by customer_name order by move_in_date) as first_residence_state,
       first_value(residence_state) over (partition by customer_name order by move_in_date desc) as last_residence_state
from @customers c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6306ef3eb1fb2d7fa5551e8ef24c704b) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    customer_name,
    max(case when rn_asc = 1 then residence_state end) first_residence_state,
    max(case when rn_desc = 1 then residence_state end) last_residence_state
from (
    select 
        c.*,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_name order by move_in_date asc) rn_asc,
        row_number() over(partition by customer_name order by move_in_date desc) rn_desc
    from @customers c
) c
where 1 in (rn_asc, rn_desc)
group by customer_name
```

The inner query ranks the records of each `customer_name` by ascending and descending `move_in_date`. Then, the outer query aggregates by `customer_name` and uses conditional expressions to pull out the `residence_state` that correspond to the first and last `move_in_date` of each customers.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2504c122021b90b386f093b0c7cd43c6)**:

```
customer_name | first_residence_state | last_residence_state
:------------ | :-------------------- | :-------------------
Chad          | Texas                 | Texas               
Jake          | Illinois              | California          
Rachel        | Wisconsin             | Arizona
```